# How to package my angular templates with grunt and browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I am using `angular1` with `browserify` and `grunt` to build the application. Currently `browserify` only packages the controllers and fetches the templates using `ng-include`in a separate ajax call.

Because of a lot of ajax calls, i want to package the templates along with the javascript.I am currently using `grunt-processhtml` to include the output from `browserify` in my `html`. What i need to know is how can i generate an output like

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/templates/*.html">
  # Template content
</script>
```

Where `*` is a wildcard of all files inside `templates` folder and they contain the content of that file. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to cache HTML templates using Angular cache service. It will inject all templates into a JS file and loaded as Angular module. 
An example of output file content:

```
angular.module('app').run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("home.html",
      '<h2>This is home page</h2>' // contents for home.html ... 
  );
});
```

First install plugin from this link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

Then load into grunt :

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-angular-templates');
```

Finally add your ngTemplate configuration. Here's an example

```
ngtemplates:  {
  app:        {
    src:      '**.html',
    dest:     'template.js'
  }
}
```